# How to configure circle.yml in order to call the database?

Tags: mysql, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

I am trying to configure the CircleCi setup. 
When I try to run the tests in my own environment then everything works out, but when I try to run it in Circle CI, then I haave got this error.

PHPUnit 5.6.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

IIIII.IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIFFFFFFFFFFFFIIII..IIIIIIIIIIII 65 / 89 ( 73%)
IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII.                                          89 / 89 (100%)

Time: 1.27 seconds, Memory: 56.00MB

There were 12 failures:

1) App\Test\TestCase\Controller\TagsControllerTest::testStages
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory' in /home/ubuntu/cemcloud2/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Database/Driver/PDODriverTrait.php:48

This is the first part of the error.

I am getting that I have an error with my database configuration.
We are using Vagrant with the script (not sure if this is viable). 
Also we are using mariaDB 10.1.19 and I have built up a test database for PHPUnit to run the tests against.
I don't know how to add this database with the configuration of mariadb and specific database.

I know that I have to add the

> database.yml.ci

to my config file so I have added it in there and it looks like this.

```
test:
adapter: mysql
database: cemcloudTest
username: root
password: ''
```

Also I have added the circle.yml to our project root and it looks like this.

```
  machine:
php:
  version: 7.0
mysql:
  version: 10.1.19
database:
override:
  - cp config/database.yml.ci config/database.yml
  - bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load
```

Could someone help me out ?

Comment: Update: 
    protected function _connect($dsn, array $config)
    {
        debug($dsn);
        $connection = new PDO(
            $dsn,
            $config['username'],
            $config['password'],
            $config['flags']
        );
        $this->connection($connection);

        return true;
    }
This is where I have put my debug and it gives me back this code. 
########## DEBUG ##########
'mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=cemcloud;charset=utf8'

Answer (score 0):

in your cicle.yml database have to be created with name you use in your test config.

```
database:
  override:
    - mysql -u ubuntu -e "create database circle_ruby_test"
```

So that, this is the db conf:

```
test: # connection name
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  host: localhost
  database: circle_ruby_test #your created DB
  username: ubuntu #default circle user
  pool: 25
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock # default sock location for circle
```

HTH:)